# Как вычислить факториал с++

Tags: c#, c++, алгоритм, математика

Здравствуйте!

**Как факториал n! вычислить в данной ситуации?**

Задание Вывести на экран таблицу значений функции Y(x) и ее разложения вряд S(x) для x, изменяющегося от a до bс шагом h = (b –a)/10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помочь тут

```
s += (pow(i,2)+1)/k*pow(x/2,i);
```

Краткий код.

```
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) 
        { 
            k=k+fact(i); 
            s += (pow(i,2)+1)/k*pow(x/2,i); 
        } 
        cout << setw(15) << x << setw(15) << y << setw(15) << s << endl; 
        x += h; 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Вашем коде стоило изменить лишь строчку

```
k=k+fact(i)
```

на

```
k=k*i
```

(перед циклом `k=1`)

Answer (score 3):

Вам **не нужно** вычислять факториал.

На С++ это будет примерно так:

```
double sum(double x, unsigned int  n)
{
    double s = 1.0;
    double term = s;
    for(int k = 1; k <= n; ++k)
        s += (term *= (k*k+1)*x/(2.0*k*((k-2)*k+2)));
    return s;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned int n = 20;
    double a = 0, b = 1; // Сами вводите...

    for(double x = a; x <= b; x += (b-a)/10)
        cout << x << "  " << sum(x,n) << "  " << (x*x/4.0+x/2.0+1.0)*exp(x/2.0) << endl;
}
```